# How to pass delegate(C#) to Haxe function?

Tags: haxe

I want to do like this:

c#:

```
class CSharpClass {
    void foo() {
        HaxeClass h = new HaxeClass();
        h.bar( () => {} );
    }
}
```

Haxe:

```
@:expose
class HaxeClass {
    public bar(f: Void->Void): Void {
        f();
    }
}
```

Generated c# code requires function parameter as haxe.lang.Function, but I can find no converter from delegate to haxe.lang.Function. Do I have to write listener class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cs.system.Action_* for that.

C#:

```
class CSharpClass {
   void foo() {
      HaxeClass h = new HaxeClass();
      h.bar(handler);
   }
   void handler(str:String){}
}
```

Haxe:

```
class HaxeClass {
   public bar(f: cs.system.Action_1<String>): Void {
      f.Invoke("foobar"); 
   }
}
```

**Note 1**
Actions with more than one parameter (Action_1, Action_2, etc) aren't available when building against .net 2.0 (the current default), only the .net 3.0 and .net 4.0 .

**Note 2**
As far as I know there is no Action_0 in the cs.system package.
Nevertheless it can be created with:

```
@:native("System.Action")
extern class Action_0 {
    function Invoke():Void;
}
```